# How to module.export both a function and other symbols

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, newman

I want to create a [newman plugin](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman#custom-reporters) as an npm package, and also use that package as a library. I have a src/index.ts file that needs to have this export to run

```
// in package newman-reporter-custom/index.ts
module.exports = function(newmanEventEmitter: any, reporterOptions: any, collectionRunOptions: any) {
    ...
};
```

I also have this bit in my package.json: `"main": "lib/index.js",` and `"outDir": "lib",` in my tsconfig.json.

Also I want to export some other classes to use the same package as a library.

```
// in package newman-reporter-custom/index.ts
import { foo } from "./foo";
export { foo };
```

I also want to export other symbols from that index.ts, so that I can require the project as a library, such as

```
// other npm package index.ts
import { foo } from "newman-reporter-custom";
```

However, it seems that in newman-reporter-custom/index.ts, I can only do one of both, either `module.exports = function(...),` or `export { foo };`.

If I try either in isolation, things seem to work fine.

If I try do do both (in various ways), either newman cannot load my package saying things like `TypeError: Reporter is not a constructor`, or I cannot import the package as a library with errors like `TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a function or null`.

It seems to me that module.exports can either be a function (a constructor), or a collection of symbols, but not both.

So what is the working clean way of both satisfying newman and providing a function export, and also exporting other symbols? I am flexible in how I require one package from the other.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript can transpile the standard ECMAScript module syntax into whatever flavour you like, so here is an example of a TypeScript module that exports an imported member:

example.ts

```
import { example } from './module';

// Export a function
export function foo() {
    return 2;
}

// Export an imported member
export { example };
```

And your calling code only knows about the example module:

```
import { foo, example } from './example';
```

Comment: You merely export 2 named functions, but what I need for newman to work is ```module.exports = function()```, so not a named function that can be imported. newman will basically do ```Reporter = require("custom-reporter"); var reporter = new Reporter(...);```

Comment: If you need a default export, you can simply add `default` to your export: `export default function foo()`

Comment: I tried that, but newman then reports ```TypeError: Reporter is not a constructor```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution using separate API module

I tried to have a different module, say src/public.ts which has

```
// in package newman-reporter-custom/public.ts
import { foo } from "./foo";
export { foo };
```

And then in dependent packages

```
// other npm package index.ts
import { foo } from "newman-reporter-custom/dist/public";
```

This solution looks a bit ugly due to the `/dist` part. (Seems discussed here https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/14970)